# How does a barrel shifter exactly work?

Tags: circuit-analysis

I am new into this and I am trying to understand, how the barrel shifter below works. I know how a multiplexer works but I don't unterstand the circuit below.

- If C=0 it shoud be a left shift. (x3,x2,x1,x0 becomes x1,x0,0,0)
- If C=1 (forgot what this shift is called) x3,x2,x1,x0 becomes x1,x0,x3,x2

[image]

But I don't understand how this circuit performs these shifts.

How does this circuit work?

I am confused about the steps with the example of C=0 what happens in the circuit and how we get from x3,x2,x1,x0 to x1,x0,0,0.

Comment: @herbrand13 you wrote that you understand multiplexers. What can't you understand in this circuit? The presence of the AND gates? (they allow to perform left shift putting zeroes in the least significant bits)

Comment: You wrote that you understand "how a multiplexer works." Taking you at your word, the only remaining question I can see, is: "Do you understand what an AND gate does and what a wire does?" There is really nothing left.

Comment: @next-hack the presence of and gates and how they interact with the multiplexers. And my other question was if someone could explain to me how the system exactly works if we have the input C=1.

Comment: Have you noticed S0 and S1? try different values for those two signals and figure out what the outputs are. A bit like a truth table. Once you have done that, the circuit should be more understandable for you.

Comment: @herbrand13 I'll write up an explanation in a half hour once I feel up to the grind, if no one else does so. Hopefully, someone else will do it. This is just completely uninteresting, as it doesn't require any insight at all. It's just a mind-numbing dredge through "stating the obvious." But I'll do it if no one else ponies up, shortly.

Comment: @herbrand13 your schematics is quite clear, follow the colors. If C = 1, the and gates act like if the other input (not C) was directly connected to their output. The circuit does not shift, it just rotates the bits. The number of positions the bits are rotated depend on S0 and S1. If C=0, zeroes are added. The circuit is a left shift (and the number of bits shifted depends on S0-S1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at the circuit when \$C = 1\$ and let's also *only* focus on the highest order bit, \$X_3\$:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQR3Ih.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've shown the other input bits in their usual places, too, because I want to talk about one case where \$S=00\$ and looking at all the input bits while also looking only at \$X_3\$ when \$S \ne 00\$. I've gotten rid of the other wiring and AND gates, for now. (Note again that this is for \$C=1\$.)

Here, you can easily see that when \$S=00\$ that each of the input bits are unshifted and unrotated. Each is simply propagated to their directly associated output wires without complexity. So you can see that it works right for this case.

Now look only at what happens with the \$X_3\$ input wire for all remaining cases of \$S\$:

1. If \$S=1\$ then \$X_3\$ appears at \$Y_0\$. This would be correct for a left-rotate-by-1 case.
2. If \$S=2\$ then \$X_3\$ appears at \$Y_1\$. This would be correct for a left-rotate-by-2 case.
3. If \$S=3\$ then \$X_3\$ appears at \$Y_2\$. This would be correct for a left-rotate-by-3 case.

It's quite clear that when \$C=1\$, the \$X_3\$ bit is rotated left by the number of bits indicated by the value of \$S\$.

Now let's look at the circuit when \$C = 1\$ and this time *only* focus on bit \$X_2\$:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fA3zMj.png)</sup>

We don't need to examine the case for \$S=0\$, since that was done already above for all of the input wires. So look only at what happens with the \$X_2\$ input wire for all remaining cases of \$S\$:

1. If \$S=1\$ then \$X_2\$ appears at \$Y_3\$. This would be correct for a left-rotate-by-1 case.
2. If \$S=2\$ then \$X_2\$ appears at \$Y_0\$. This would be correct for a left-rotate-by-2 case.
3. If \$S=3\$ then \$X_2\$ appears at \$Y_1\$. This would be correct for a left-rotate-by-3 case.

I won't belabor the other two remaining input wires. I think you should be able to walk forward for the remaining two situations on your own.

---

Let's look at the circuit when \$C = 0\$ and let's also *only* focus on the lowest order bit, \$X_0\$:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftH1wj.png)</sup>

Again, we don't need to examine the case for \$S=0\$, since that was done already earlier above for all of the input wires. So look only at what happens with the \$X_0\$ input wire for all remaining cases of \$S\$:

1. If \$S=1\$ then \$X_0\$ appears at \$Y_1\$. Correct for the left-shift-by-1 case.
2. If \$S=2\$ then \$X_0\$ appears at \$Y_2\$. Correct for the left-shift-by-2 case.
3. If \$S=3\$ then \$X_0\$ appears at \$Y_3\$. Correct for the left-shift-by-3 case.

Also take note of the \$0\$ values there. When \$S=3\$, notice that \$Y_0\$, \$Y_1\$, and \$Y_2\$ are all \$0\$. That's also correct for a left-shift-by-3, correct? When \$S=2\$, notice that \$Y_0\$ and \$Y_1\$ are \$0\$. That's correct for a left-shift-by-2, correct? When \$S=1\$, notice that \$Y_0\$ is \$0\$. That's correct for a left-shift-by-1, correct?

So far, it's doing exactly what you want.

Now, let's look at \$X_1\$:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZC7NY.png)</sup>

That is also correct, as you can see that \$X_1\$ appears where it should, when it should.

Etc.

---

Another way you can look at this is that this barrel shifter is designed to perform a ***left rotate by*** \$S\$. Setting \$C=0\$ doesn't change the rotate behavior. All it does is cause the barrel shifter to ***mask off*** (to \$0\$) any bits shifted off of the left end before they are rotated. It still performs a rotate, though. (In effect.)